# Ruby Syntax Blather

Tags: ruby, syntax, xmpp

I'm taking a look at this example

```
require 'blather/client/dsl'

module App
  extend Blather::DSL

  def self.run
    EM.run { client.run }
  end

  setup 'echo@jabber.local', 'echo'

  # Auto approve subscription requests
  subscription :request? do |s|
    write_to_stream s.approve!
  end

  # Echo back what was said
  message :chat?, :body do |m|
    write_to_stream m.reply
  end
end

trap(:INT) { EM.stop }
trap(:TERM) { EM.stop }

App.run
```

I understand everything within this code but the EM. references. For example, in self.run what is EM.run referring to? It appears to take a block but I can't find any reference on what EM is.

I get what the code does, but I can't find any documentation or if this is a ruby feature/blather feature.

Comment: That does appear to be what it is. Thanks a ton. Were you able to find this as a dependency or something somewhere within the blather docs?

Comment: So, the answers tells you this? It is the longer version of mine.

Comment: If it is a gem, check Rubygems.org for dependencies: http://rubygems.org/gems/blather

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EM` is a class. I'm going to assume it stands for EventMachine since blather uses it, but I'm not 100% sure about that.

Comment: You are almost right. `EM` is a module. I have found it in a Github. https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/blob/dd675e4d061785cfe8240cd98e4c7525cd6fdae5/lib/eventmachine.rb#L1535 https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/blob/dd675e4d061785cfe8240cd98e4c7525cd6fdae5/lib/eventmachine.rb#L72